# SwiftUI: Rotated VStack results in aliased ("jaggy") drawing

Tags: swiftui

I have a `View` with a `VStack` containing a `Rectangle` and a `Spacer`. The view is rotated with the `rotationEffect()` modifier.

The result looks bad as it is not antialiased.

How can I rotate the vertical stack, but having the output antialiased as I expect?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RectangleView()
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.green)
                .frame(width: 2, height: 200)
            Spacer()
        }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 130))
    }
}
```

[image: jaggy rectangle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this is a product of using `Rectangle()` and similar default shapes, specifically when filling them. I can't attest to the precise reason why, but I do know that this problem is best solved with `Path`s instead.

```
Path { path in
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200))
}
.stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2.0)
```

Here's a way you could do this inline. If you want a reusable structure though, do something like this:

```
struct Thingy: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        // you can use the rect properties to center things this way
        return path
     }
}
```

With either approach, rotating them should no longer cause this jaggedness.
It may be possible to achieve the same result when applying `stroke`s instead of `fill`s and `foregroundColor`s, but `Paths` were more suited to my needs anyway, so that is where I found my solution to this problem. I haven't run these exact code snippets, but I can attest to their efficacy as I've encountered the same frustration in my own projects.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you! Interestingly, no aliasing when just stroking the shape, but if it is stroked and the background is filled, the aliasing shows up.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to clip the shape and specify to use antialiasing:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .fill(.green)
    .clipped(antialiased: true)
```

This is how it looks:

[image]